# Best mobile UI design for deselecting a categorized list of selected items?

Tags: lists, mobile-web, copy-paste

Very broadly speaking, I'm developing an application where you search for a keyword, then the application displays a list of items. Each item has a classification. Selecting items by clicking a checkbox next to them and clicking "Copy" does two things:

1. Copies the selected items to the clipboard
2. Moves the selected items to other lists below this list, according to the items' classifications.

For example, given this list:

[image: list with "Copy button" on top]

selecting "Alfreds F." and "Sundhar P.", and then click the "Copy" button on top of all these copies those entries to the clipboard, and then moves them to other lists, so the Webpage looks like this:

[image: list with moved items]

The user should be able to remove items from the clipboard.

How should I let this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering functionality on mobile phones, put an action button near each section. The Name/Nationality section has the "Copy" button, and the itemized list section has a "Remove" button.

If no items have been copied the "Remove" button is disabled:

[image: copy]

Once items have been copied the "Remove" button becomes active:

[image: remove]

Comment: Efficient & less room for error than your other answer :)

Answer (score 0):

A mouseover can reveal a "remove" option:

> Results
>
> __ Amelia Earhart, American
>
> Germans
>
> **Alfreds Futterkiste**   (remove)   **<-**
>
> Indians
>
> Sundhar Pichai
>
> Americans
>
> (this list is blank)

Clicking "remove" removes the selection from the sub-list and restores it to the *Results* list.

The "remove" activator can be be a descriptive word: remove, delete, undo..., or an icon: trash can, ?... And when not activated can be hidden or dimmed. If an icon, a descriptive flyover helps.

Comment: Hi bloodyKnuckles, that looks great for a desktop UI, but I'm not sure that fits for a mobile UI, which is what I'm focusing on right now.

I added some diagrams that I hope will help visualize the app's UI.

Comment: @MontanaBurrFreelancing On mobile don't hide the "remove" link/button, so mouseover is not required.